# edit CSS animation duration with JS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, duration

How could I change the duration of `flipHeads` from 3s to 0s using pure Javascript?

**CSS:**

```
.animate-Heads{
  animation: flipHeads 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can change it this way: `document.querySelector(".animate-Heads").style.animationDuration = "0s";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 const animateHeads = document.getElementsByClassName('animate-Heads')

 /*animateHeads is now an array which contains elements that have 'animate-Heads' as class name , saying you want to change the duration of the first element */

 animateHeads[0].style.animationDuration = '0s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not fan on inline css so i would add class to element.
`document.querySelector('.animate-Heads').classList.add('remove-duration')`

`.animate-Heads.remove-duration{ animation-duration: 0s; }`